# HQL with IN clause

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

Query is:

```
select e from Customer 
join e.Address ad where ad.Id =:Id and :houseNo in (ad.houseNos);
```

I am setting all parameters in query properly, but I am getting syntax error exception.

So, my question is can we pass the `houseNo` as an input parameter?
Query will select the address of customer and his house should be one of houses of that street address.

Data Model:-- Customer is main table that has a list of Address and in turn Address has a list of house no. I have address id and house no. So, I need to get customer details who is living in specified house no of specified address.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got three things wrong:

1. You did not define your alias
2. The uppercased attribute names
3. Your `IN` seems to be used in the opposite way (it must be `attribute in (values)` and you're trying `values in (attribute)`

Try this:

```
select e from Customer as e
join e.address as ad // I assume address is your attribute and is declared as address (not Address), so it starts with lowercase
where ad.id = :Id and ad.houseNos in (:houseNo);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but preferably without "... in in ..." just "... in ..."

Comment: Just fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: Your understanding of question is correct. Sorry for not providing complete data model.

Comment: But my situational demand is that I have house no in that street and I need to confirm whatever house no I am passing as the input field should be there in the house no list of that street address.

Comment: Customer is main table that has a list of Address and in turn Address has a list of house no. I have address id and house no. So, I need to get customer details who is living in specified house no of specified address.

Comment: Don't worry for signature and attribute names. I can take care of it. Please let me know if you have a solution for this.

Comment: @user144121, it seems to lead to another question. Once your original problem has been answered and now there's something else, I believe you should create a new question, as it's said here - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306958/handle-question-changing-topic-problem. I will be happy to check that if you do it. Cheers.

Comment: @Tom Sorry to reiterate but my question is same though I edited it to provide more clarification. But whatever solution is proposed, it is not the proper solution I am looking for. It would be great if you propose proper solution

Comment: @user144121, your problem has changed. Your original question stated "I am getting syntax error exception". Now it seems you want to filter your results depending on your model. If the query now doesn't present a `syntax exception`, in my opinion it should be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research, I found out this is not possible. We can handle asked scenario using nested query.